# Executing Silverlight app from another mac desktop application

Tags: objective-c, macos, silverlight-oob

Is it possible to execute silverlight application from mac desktop application developed using Objective - C. i.e.

Mac desktop app using Objective-C -> User clicks on some button -> Silverlight application should get launched.

Actually what I think is but don't know whether it is correct or not :

" If silverlight is installed locally on your machine,it act as an separate  application & from one application we can execute another application by calling its .app file "

Thanx in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"MySilverlightApp"];`

Theres several calls on NSWorkspace to do this , thats the most simple of them.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I have one more question,that if I launch such type of Silverlight application from my mac aap,then whether Apple will reject my app ? since I have read in apple guidelines that : 2.24 Apps that use deprecated or optionally installed technologies (e.g., Java, Rosetta) will be rejected

Comment: I can't say for certain but it wouldn't be used by your app just called by your app if you want to go all lawyer speak. Most likely no IMHO. Unless you are bundling the SL app with your own app.